# In rspec, user.invoices.count says 0 but it shows it has models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am building a user rspec test. I have many invoices that I associated with user. In the console, when I do user.invoices, it shows a hash of invoices. However, when I do user.invoices.count to get the number of invoices for that user, it says 0. Here's my code:

```
  before(:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)

    @invoice = FactoryGirl.build(:invoice)
    @invoice.issue_date = "2013-01-01"
    @user.invoices << @invoice
```

then if i put a debugger in there, it says count = 0. here's the output:

```
(rdb:1) p user.invoices
[#<Invoice id: nil, user_id: 279, issue_date: "2013-01-01", due_date: nil, payment_term: "Net 15", discount: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, client_id: 140, client_invoice_id: 1, custom_message: nil, sent_to: nil, status: nil, public_id: "1234", grand_total: nil, user_name: nil, company_name: nil, custom_email_message: nil, address_line_one: nil, address_line_two: nil>, 
 #<Invoice id: nil, user_id: 281, issue_date: "2013-01-01", due_date: nil, payment_term: "Net 15", discount: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, client_id: 141, client_invoice_id: 1, custom_message: nil, sent_to: nil, status: nil, public_id: "1234", grand_total: nil, user_name: nil, company_name: nil, custom_email_message: nil, address_line_one: nil, address_line_two: nil>, 
 #<Invoice id: nil, user_id: 283, issue_date: "2012-01-01", due_date: nil, payment_term: "Net 15", discount: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, client_id: 142, client_invoice_id: 1, custom_message: nil, sent_to: nil, status: nil, public_id: "1234", grand_total: nil, user_name: nil, company_name: nil, custom_email_message: nil, address_line_one: nil, address_line_two: nil>, 
 #<Invoice id: nil, user_id: 285, issue_date: "2011-01-01", due_date: nil, payment_term: "Net 15", discount: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, client_id: 143, client_invoice_id: 1, custom_message: nil, sent_to: nil, status: nil, public_id: "1234", grand_total: nil, user_name: nil, company_name: nil, custom_email_message: nil, address_line_one: nil, address_line_two: nil>]
(rdb:1) p user.invoices.count
0
```

why is count not working properly? this is the test i'm trying to get to pass:

```
 it "should return the correct count of all invoices in the specified year" do
   # there are two invoices in 2013
   user = @user
   user.count_of_invoices_by_year("2013", :total).should == 2
 end
```

count_of_invoices_by_year uses .count and it isn't working properly

Comment: There is also something strange here. The user_id is different for each invoice. Why is that?

Comment: you're right...i'm not sure why the user_id's are all different...i'm using the same user for each one..why would that be?

Comment: I don't know, but I'm curious. Maybe time for another question? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because sending .count queries the database using a COUNT(*).  Since you're using FactoryGirl.build, there are no records in the DB, so it's returning 0.

See also:
http://rhnh.net/2007/09/26/counting-activerecord-associations-count-size-or-length
Which explains the difference between .size, .length, and .count.

Edit:
Here's how to test your method (this will save the records to the DB, but they will be destroyed after the test)

```
before(:each) do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)

  @invoice = FactoryGirl.create(:invoice)
  @invoice.issue_date = "2013-01-01"
  @invoice.save
  @user.invoices << @invoice
  @user.save
```

Comment: interesting..you are right. so how to I test a model method that has .count in it?

Comment: See my updated answer - this will create the records in the DB, so .count will work.

Comment: thanks. saving wasn't necessary when using .create instead of .build FYI